# Preserving polymorphism in class hierarchies (C++)

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic, runtime, polymorphism

Something like this must have been asked on SO before, but I failed to track down an answer directly addressing the below. It is a very basic question, but, away from my books, I'm blanking.

I define a parent and child type class:

```
class token{...};  

class word: public token{...};
```

Class token shares a variable with word; word further refines token. Neither class is virtual.

I have a helper function of the following signature, with representative creation code indicated:

```
token  
maker()  
{  
...  
case ...: // (1)
  return token(...);
case ...: // (2)
  return word(...);
...
},
```

the idea being obviously that it creates the appropriate type, and returns it as a token.

I mean to use the returned object by statically assigning it to a token type, with dynamic resolution to the true type (word or token) when appropriate, as in

```
token t = maker(); // I want to be able to use the methods of word, if 
                   // maker actually made a word (true polymorphic behavior)
```

I realize that this should be by pointer or reference to enable polymorphism, and that in the current design maker() slices word types to token types; but am blanking on how to do adjust the above best to achieve my goal. Yes, I am embarassed.

Comment: If you want to not carro references or pointers when doing polymorphism, Consider to use type-erasure or [non-intrusive polymorphism](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil) (The later could be viewed as a free-function-based form of type erasure)

Comment: Use pointers for polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For polymorphism to work, you need virtual functions and must work with pointers and references, not the type itself.

Case in point:

```
token* maker(...) {
    ...
    switch(...) {
    case ...: // (1)
        return new token(...);
    case ...: // (2)
        return new word(...);
    }
    ...
}
```

Though perhaps you should use `std::unique_pointer<token>` for returns and parameters which assign ownership. Also look at `std::shared_pointer`.
Delete them with:

```
delete pToken;
```

Obviously, you need a virtual dtor in token itself.

Answer (score 0):

Return a `std::unique_ptr<token>` in maker. Although I have to say that when you say

> Class token shares a variable with word; word further refines token.
>   Neither class is virtual.

I am not sure if public inheritance is appropriate. It sounds more that word uses token to share implementation because there are not virtual functions.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? My answer looks quite the same as the accepted one to me.

Answer (score -1):

first, use pointers. second, use dynamic_cast<>

change maker to return pointer
and use it like:

```
token* t = maker();
if( word* w = dynamic_cast<word*>(t) )
{
    // if you get here, w is a valid word
}
```

Comment: As currently structured, such attempts will point to (refence) a local variable.

Comment: use with Deduplicator's `maker()`